# How to close 22 (so I can open it)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall

I have been trying to get ssh to work between an Ubuntu VM and my Xubuntu system.

(Note: My Xubuntu system is running on Chrome OS)
SSH has hangs until a timeout, this tells me that something is blocking it.

Nmap to confirm:

```
gizmoz@ubuntu:~$ nmap -Pn -p 22  192.168.1.21

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-11-11 21:50 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.21
Host is up.

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.20 seconds
```

I assumed it was a firewall issue but Xbuntu does not have ufw service.

Now this is clearly my network so I know there are no direct answers to my knowledge. But could anybody point me in the right direction?

(I would be happy to run commands as needed)

Comment: `ufw` is just a management tool for the actual firewall subsystem in the kernel. Your distribution might manage it some other way. Use `iptables -L -vn` as root to see if there are any iptables firewall rules in place, regardless of the management tool used. Also try `nft list ruleset`, in case a newer nftables system is used to manage the firewall rules instead.

Comment: Your hostsystem uses a virtual networkdevice for connection with vm's. The IP-addresses of the external and the virtual networkdevice differ. Is the IP mentioned in your `nmap` command indeed the one of the virtual networkcard ?

Comment: `ufw`, `iptables` and `nft` all not found. Are there some older firewall tools? I believe my kernel is a bit older.